# Finding the maximum of a pixel in an RGB image

Tags: matlab, max, rgb

I have a MxNx3 matrix that represents an RGB image. I am trying to retrieve, for each pixel, the maximum among R, G and B. This would be made easy by using a for loop, which I do not wish to do for performance reasons.
How could I go about doing that? My idea is to use find and max in the following way and get an MxN matrix:

```
maxRGB = find(max(rgbImage(i, j, :)));
```

But I am not sure how I could eliminate i and j.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [`max`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/max.html) function allows to specify along which dimension the maximum value is determined. The standard value is the first dimension. In your case, you'll want to calculate the maximum along the third dimension of the array:

```
maxValue = max(rgbImage,[],3);
```

Which returns a matrix of size MxN containing the maximum value of each pixel.

For example, lets take a random 3x3 RGB image. Applying the `max` function as above yields

```
rgbImage = rand(3,3,3);
maxValue =  max(rgbImage,[],3);

maxValue =
    0.6948    0.7094    0.7655
    0.6555    0.7547    0.7952
    0.9502    0.3816    0.8235
```

These are the maximal values which were present in `rgbImage` at each pixel location. But, you don't know if this value was in the R, G or B pixel.

To find out, which color was maximal, you can use the second (optional) argument of `max`, which is the index of the found maximum:

```
[~,maxIndex] = max(rgbImage,[],3);
```

which in this small example was

```
maxIndex =
     2     3     2
     1     3     2
     2     2     1
```

where `1` corresponds to R, `2` corresponds to G and `3` corresponds to B.
To find all pixels, in which the red component was the largest, you can use the [`find`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/find.html) function (probably with 2 output arguments: row and column)

```
[xRed,yRed] = find(maxIndex == 1)

xRed =
     2
     3


yRed =
     1
     3
```

So for the pixels at `(2,1)` and at `(3,3)` the red component was the largest. This is exactly what the matrix `maxIndex` also shows us.

Comment: So maxIndex will be an MxN matrix too?

Comment: Yes, `maxIndex` has the same size as `maxValue`. For every element in `maxValue`, the index (i.e. 1, 2 or 3 = R, G or B) is stored in `maxIndex`.

Comment: Yes exactly. I edited my answer to try to show that. Does this help?